# Angular / Jasmine Testing - How to Stub Both a Constructor and Property

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In Jasmine, I can mock a constructor function with the following:

```
window.Notification = jasmine.createSpy('Notification').and.returnValue('returned value');
```

I can stub a property for the same object with an assignment operation:

```
window.Notification = {
    permission: 'granted'
};
```

How do I do both?  I have the following code I'd like to test:

```
if(Notification.permission == 'granted'){
    var notificationObject = new Notification('new message', {
        body: 'body of message'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`jasmine.createSpy` returns function and functions like any other objects can have properties. As long as you don't override properties used by Jasmine like `and` or `calls` it should be safe to add properties to created spy functions:

`var mockNotification = jasmine.createSpy('Notification').and.returnValue('returned value');
mockNotification.permission = 'granted';
window.Notification = mockNotification;`